# Absolute index of the read() function

Tags: python-3.x, file-io

When you use the python `read()` function on a file, is there a way to determine the absolute index that it is 'seeking'? For example, lets say you were to call `read(1)` on a file three times. It's at index 3 of the file, but is there a way to determine this via some built-in function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f = open('data', 'r')
f.read(2)
f.tell() # prints 2
f.read(3)
f.tell() # prints 5
```